# ffmpeg: extract subtitles from mp4 files, when subtitles are embedded as binary data stream

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4, video-subtitles

What I am trying to do is to extract subtitles which are embedded in a `.mp4` file. Goal is to have the `.mp4` file and the subtitles uploaded together on HTML5.
What I would normally do is looking for the subtitles stream with `ffprobe` then do something along (assuming stream 2 is the subtitle stream)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map:0:2 out.vtt
```

Now I have this file where, applying the command above, the following error is generated

```
Exactly one WebVTT stream is needed.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

I have tried a similar solution

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -an -codec:s:0.2 srt sub.srt
```

without success:

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

It turns out the subtitles stream is some binary data which I would have to decode somehow (I was also able to dump the binary content of it to no further use)

```
Stream #0:2(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

Any idea about a solution, or at least a way around it?

Comment: _"...Or at least a way around it?"_ Maybe try to just extract the text yourself (by code). First download a free **hex editor** (if you don't have one) then check the "text" side (usually at right-hand side) to **search** for the first words of first sentence in your subtitles. If found, that is the bytes data that you must extract from your file. Please first confirm if you found anything or not, then we can move on to some further advice.

Comment: That sounds like a way to go! I'll get back as soon as I have tried what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use the copy codec:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:s:2 -c copy subtitle.srt
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that I also tried something along the line, no success: `SRT supports only a single subtitles stream.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --`